# Syslink control - normal (double) click notification?

Tags: c++, winapi

Normal statics have SS_NOTIFY for recieving (double)clicks. How can I handle the same events for Syslink controls when "normal" text within them is clicked, not the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any easy approach. Probably the easiest is to [superclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633569%28VS.85%29.aspx#winproc_superclassing) a syslink and handle `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP`. You could also [subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633569%28VS.85%29.aspx#winproc_subclassing), but There's little difference in difficulty for a less flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/bb775583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
sample code:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    //NMHDR* pHeader = (NMHDR*)lParam;
    //NMLINK* pNMLink = (NMLINK*)lParam;
    //LITEM iItem = pNMLink->item;
    switch(((NMHDR *)lParam)->code)
    {
    case NM_CLICK:
        { 
            if(int(wParam) == IDC_SYSLINK_LOGIN)
            {
                //do something
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;
     }
```